# Kapt exception (KaptExecution)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kapt

I'm working to add room to my project written in Kotlin but I always got this error.

Users data class

```
@Entity 
data class Users(

@PrimaryKey
val id: String? = "",

@ColumnInfo(name = "userFullName")
val name: String?,

@ColumnInfo(name = "userEmail")
val email: String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "userPassword")
val password: String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "userBDay", defaultValue = "")
val birthday: String?
)
```

UserDao

```
@Dao interface UserDao {

@Insert
fun insertUser(user: Users)

@Delete
suspend fun deleteUser(user: Users)

@Query("SELECT * FROM users")
fun getAllUsers(): List<Users>
}
```

User database

```
@Database(entities = [Users::class], version = 1)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: UserDatabase? = null

        fun getUserDatabase(context: Context): UserDatabase {

            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    UserDatabase::class.java,
                    "usersDB"
                ).build()

                this.instance = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I build it, I got this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:

> 2021-02-14T16:35:38.826+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

I got this error in every code I've written and downloaded from github.

I tried solutions in these links:

[Repeated Build fails "To use Coroutine features, you must add `ktx`......."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58671990/repeated-build-fails-to-use-coroutine-features-you-must-add-ktx)

[How to get rid of Incremental annotation processing requested warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670510/how-to-get-rid-of-incremental-annotation-processing-requested-warning)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848845/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin-compilation-error/45016580#45016580)

[A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131564/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec)

[A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks)

I also thought it could be caused by AS and I downloaded other version of AS, same thing happened

Comment: Could you post gradle configuration for the module with the DB, and full error, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the android studio ide and kotlin version. So, when I updated the next version or downgraded to the other versions the problem's solved

Answer (score 0):

@Insert
fun insertUser(user: Users)

Change this to

@Insert
suspend fun insertUser(user: Users)

Insert shouldn't be done on UI thread. That's is the possible cause of this error.

Comment: Also did you try to check the exact error as suggested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131564/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec

Comment: Run this from command line: ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace

Comment: Hey. Thanks, I tried it already but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Will you please share the --stacktrace output which you are getting after running the above command?

Comment: It's a little bit long, so it's here
https://justpaste.it/2e8kg

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was the @Installin annotation with ApplicationComponent::class
I just change it to SingletonComponent::class

Befor:

*@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)*

After:
 *@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)*

also removed the @Singleton annotation from function in my module class

in your viewModel class you should inject the constructor like this:

*class MainViewModel @Inject constructor (
private val repository: Repository,
@ApplicationContext application: MyApplication
):AndroidViewModel(application)*

and in your activity or fragment init your viewmodel like this:

*val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()*